# Plotting multiindex pandas DataFrame with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a multi-index pandas `DataFrame` with the following structure that I got from a `groupby` operation:

```
                   count
year  month  day
2010  1      1       1
             2       3
             3       6
             4      24
             5      31
```

This continues for many days, months, and years.  The `DataFrame` has three indices (`year`, `month`, and `day`).

What I'd like to do is use `matplotlib` to plot the `count` as a function of the `date`.  There are several examples online of plotting dates in matplotlib, so really what I need to do is:

**Question**:

1) How can I build a separate array or `DataFrame` that is two columns, first column being the `date` and second column being the `count`?

**What I tried**

```
for idx, val in enumerate(df3.body):
    print val
```

That only prints the values of `count` row by row, but I'm not sure how to access the `date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  I was actually pretty close in what I tried.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(df.count):
    print val

    # Get the index of this row
    d = df.iloc[idx].name
```

I didn't realize the `.name` held the index of the DataFrame.  Problem Solved.